# Curl to python. Invalid request format: Unexpected character

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a valid CURL and I want to convert it to python requests

```
curl 'https://ok.ru/web-api/v2/search/suggestCities' \
  -H 'authority: ok.ru' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' \
  -H 'strd: false' \
  -H 'ok-screen: searchResult' \
  -H 'content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'tkn: xxjv3tHq1a6zyiHKDMCIcR3x7XFCO7St' \
  -H 'origin: https://ok.ru' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://ok.ru/' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cookie: bci=6040686626671285074; _statid=a741e249-8adb-4c9a-8344-6e7e8360700a; viewport=762; _hd=h; tmr_lvid=ea50ffe34e269b16d061756e9a17b263; tmr_lvidTS=1609852383671; AUTHCODE=VCmGBS9d9sIxDnxN-hzApvPxPoLNADWCZLYyW8JOTcolv2dJjwH7ALYd8dNP9ljxZZuLvoKsDXgozEUt-PjSwXYEDt4syizx1I2LS58gb49kCFae-5uIap--mtLsff2ZqGbFqK5r7buboZ0_3; JSESSIONID=adca48748b8f0c58a926f5e4948f42c0c0aa9463798a9240.1f3566ed; LASTSRV=ok.ru; msg_conf=2468555756792551; TZ=6; _flashVersion=0; CDN=; nbp=; tmr_detect=0%7C1609852395541; cudr=0; klos=0; tmr_reqNum=4; TZD=6.200; TD=200' \
  --data-binary $'{\n  "id": 24,\n  "parameters": {\n    "query": "Londo"\n  }\n}' \
  --compressed
```

I used https://curl.trillworks.com/ and received

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'ok.ru',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'strd': 'false',
    'ok-screen': 'searchResult',
    'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
    'tkn': 'xxjv3tHq1a6zyiHKDMCIcR3x7XFCO7St',
    'origin': 'https://ok.ru',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://ok.ru/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'bci=6040686626671285074; _statid=a741e249-8adb-4c9a-8344-6e7e8360700a; viewport=762; _hd=h; tmr_lvid=ea50ffe34e269b16d061756e9a17b263; tmr_lvidTS=1609852383671; AUTHCODE=VCmGBS9d9sIxDnxN-hzApvPxPoLNADWCZLYyW8JOTcolv2dJjwH7ALYd8dNP9ljxZZuLvoKsDXgozEUt-PjSwXYEDt4syizx1I2LS58gb49kCFae-5uIap--mtLsff2ZqGbFqK5r7buboZ0_3; JSESSIONID=adca48748b8f0c58a926f5e4948f42c0c0aa9463798a9240.1f3566ed; LASTSRV=ok.ru; msg_conf=2468555756792551; TZ=6; _flashVersion=0; CDN=; nbp=; tmr_detect=0%7C1609852395541; cudr=0; klos=0; tmr_reqNum=4; TZD=6.200; TD=200',
}

data = '${\\n "id": 24,\\n "parameters": {\\n "query": "Londo"\\n }\\n}'

response = requests.post('https://ok.ru/web-api/v2/search/suggestCities', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.content)
```

The python code returns error. **How can I fix the error?**

> b'{"success":false,"error":{"type":1,"typeName":"INVALID_REQUEST","errorCode":"api.invalid-format","errorMessage":"Invalid request format: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@44bfb87a; line: 1, column: 3]"},"result":null}'

Comment: if portal expect JSON data then you can use `post(..., json=data)` and then you don't have to create string in `data` but use normal dictionary.

Comment: char `$` is not part of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page expects `JSON` data so you can use normal dictionary with data (instead of string) and `json= ...` instead of `data=...`

```
data = {"id": 24,"parameters": {"query": "Londo"}}

response = requests.post(..., json=data)
```

If you want to send it as `data` then you need normal `\n` instead of `\\n`

```
data = '{\n "id": 24,\n "parameters": {\n "query": "Londo"\n }\n}'

response = requests.post(..., data=data)
```

But usually servers don't care of data formatting so you can send it even without `\n`, and without spaces.

```
data = '{"id":24,"parameters":{"query":"Londo"}}'

response = requests.post(..., data=data)
```

---

Full code

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'ok.ru',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'strd': 'false',
    'ok-screen': 'searchResult',
    'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
    'tkn': 'xxjv3tHq1a6zyiHKDMCIcR3x7XFCO7St',
    'origin': 'https://ok.ru',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://ok.ru/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'bci=6040686626671285074; _statid=a741e249-8adb-4c9a-8344-6e7e8360700a; viewport=762; _hd=h; tmr_lvid=ea50ffe34e269b16d061756e9a17b263; tmr_lvidTS=1609852383671; AUTHCODE=VCmGBS9d9sIxDnxN-hzApvPxPoLNADWCZLYyW8JOTcolv2dJjwH7ALYd8dNP9ljxZZuLvoKsDXgozEUt-PjSwXYEDt4syizx1I2LS58gb49kCFae-5uIap--mtLsff2ZqGbFqK5r7buboZ0_3; JSESSIONID=adca48748b8f0c58a926f5e4948f42c0c0aa9463798a9240.1f3566ed; LASTSRV=ok.ru; msg_conf=2468555756792551; TZ=6; _flashVersion=0; CDN=; nbp=; tmr_detect=0%7C1609852395541; cudr=0; klos=0; tmr_reqNum=4; TZD=6.200; TD=200',
}

data = {"id": 24,"parameters": {"query": "Londo"}}
response = requests.post('https://ok.ru/web-api/v2/search/suggestCities', headers=headers, json=data)

#data = '{\n"id": 24,\n"parameters": {\n"query": "Londo"\n}\n}'
#data = '{"id": 24,"parameters": {"query": "Londo"}}'
#data = '{"id":24,"parameters":{"query":"Londo"}}'
#response = requests.post('https://ok.ru/web-api/v2/search/suggestCities', headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.content)
```

Result

```
b'{"id":"24","success":true,"result":[{"id":"10396742690","text":{"value":"\xd0\x9b\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd","highlights":[{"from":0,"to":5}]}},{"id":"10416110054","text":{"value":"\xd0\x9b\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd","highlights":[{"from":0,"to":5}]}},{"id":"10394207490","text":{"value":"\xd0\x9b\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8","highlights":[{"from":0,"to":5}]}},{"id":"10422250443","text":{"value":"\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81. \xd0\x9b\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe (\xd0\x97\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4) (\xd0\x9e\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbb\xd1\x83\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd)","highlights":[{"from":5,"to":10}]}},{"id":"10397418605","text":{"value":"\xd1\x81. \xd0\x9b\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe (\xd0\x9e\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbb\xd1\x83\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd)","highlights":[{"from":3,"to":8}]}},{"id":"152804","text":{"value":"\xd0\xb4. \xd0\x9b\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe-\xd0\xa3\xd1\x81\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4 (\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x83\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x81/\xd1\x81) (\xd0\x91\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd)","highlights":[{"from":3,"to":8}]}},{"id":"152906","text":{"value":"\xd0\xb4. \xd0\x9b\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe-\xd0\x9f\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8c (\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x83\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x81/\xd1\x81) (\xd0\x91\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd)","highlights":[{"from":3,"to":8}]}},{"id":"10393597847","text":{"value":"\xd0\x9c\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb","highlights":[{"from":0,"to":0}]}},{"id":"10402241038","text":{"value":"\xd0\x9d\xd1\x8c\xd1\x8e-\xd0\x9b\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd","highlights":[{"from":4,"to":9}]}}]}'
```

---

Char `$` in `curl` version is not part of data but only information for `curl` how to get data - or maybe rather information for `bash` how to send this data to `curl`.

[Understanding two flags and a dollar sign in a CURL command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115612/understanding-two-flags-and-a-dollar-sign-in-a-curl-command)

Answer (score 0):

Pls. send the `data` in a valid format. Data should be dictionary, list of tuples, bytes or a file object to send to the specified url